# How to count pairs of numbers whose difference (absolute value) equals the same number

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The problem I am trying to solve is this:

Two distinct integers are chosen at random and without replacement from
the first six positive integers. Compute the expected value of the absolute value of the difference of these two numbers.

So $X=\{\left|a_1-a_2 \right| : a_1,a_2 \in \{1,\dots, 6\}, a_1 \not = a_2\} = \{1, \dots, 5\}$

So I know that $E(X)=\sum_{x \in X} xp_X(x)$ for a discrete random variable, which I think X would be in this case.

Now I need to find $p_X(x)=P(\{c:X(c)=x\})$ and here I am having problems. I think the total number of events is $6\choose2$, but how do I count the possible pairs of numbers whose difference is equal to 1,2,3,4,5 without writing them out by hand?

For instance $1=|1-2|,|2-1|,|2-3|,|3-2|,\dots$ becomes very tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, there are only ${6 \choose 2}=15$ pairs, so counting them all by hand is not so hard.  Order doesn't matter, so you can insist that the first number be less than the second.  Then you might notice the pattern that there are $5$ pairs with difference $1$, $4$ pairs with difference $2$, down to $1$ pair with difference $5$.

Answer (score 1):

If you're counting events using ${6 \choose 2}$ then you don't want to count $|1-2|$ and $|2-1|$ separately. Using "choose" notation implies the order the numbers were picked doesn't matter. If you want to take order into account then the number of events is $6*5$.

Counting the number of pairs with a specific difference is not too hard. Let your drawn numbers be $n_1$ and $n_2$ and start by looking at differences of 1.

If $n_1 = 1$ then $n_2=2$, if $n_1=2$ then $n_2=3$ and so on up to $n_1=5$ and $n_2=6$. So there are 5 combinations of numbers with difference of 1.

Similarly, if the difference is 2 then $n_1$ goes from 1 to 4 and $n_2$ goes from 3 to 6. So there are 4 combinations.

Do the same thing for differences of 3, 4, 5.

Answer (score 0):

This symmetry runs throughout.  For a moment we will assume that $a_2 > a_1$ and then remember that we have to consider the cases that the values are flipped.

Suppose 
$a_2 - a_1 = 1$

$a_1$ can be as large as 5 and for any $a_1 \in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ there is a corresponding $a_2$ such that $a_2 - a_1 = 1$  So, there are 5 possible values for $a_1$

but if $a_2-a_1 = 5$ then $a_1 = 1$

$E[|a_2 - a_1|] = \frac {2(1\cdot 5 + 2\cdot 4 + 3\cdot 3 + 4 \cdot 2 + 5\cdot 1)}{30}$